# How can I save user's followers in firebase? React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections in my database one called `Buyers` and the other called `Sellers`. Whenever the buyer follows the seller I save the seller's `Uid` in a subcollection called `userFollowings` in the `Buyers` collection.

How can I save the followers Uids too? Save the buyer `uid` in a subcollection called `userFollowers` in the `Sellers` collection every time a buyer follows a seller?

here's my code:

```
const onFollow = () => {
  firebase.firestore()
      .collection("Buyers")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .collection("userFollowings")
      .doc(props.route.params.uid)
      .set({})


}
const onUnfollow = () => {
  firebase.firestore()
      .collection("Buyers")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .collection("userFollowings")
      .doc(props.route.params.uid)
      .delete()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#batched-writes), as follows, in such a way the two writes complete atomically.

```
  const db = firebase.firestore();

  const onFollow = () => {
    const buyerID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const followerID = props.route.params.uid;

    const buyerFollowerRef = db
      .collection('Buyers')
      .doc(buyerID)
      .collection('userFollowings')
      .doc(followerID);

    const sellerFollowerRef = db
      .collection('Sellers')
      .doc(followerID)
      .collection('userFollowers')
      .doc(buyerID);

    const batch = db.batch();
    batch.set(buyerFollowerRef, { foo: 'bar' });
    batch.set(sellerFollowerRef, { foo: 'bar' });
    batch.commit();
  };
```

For the `onUnfollow` function, use `batch.delete()`.

---

You could also use a Cloud Function triggered when the doc in the `userFollowings` subcollection is created.

This would be the way to go if the end-user does not have the permission to write to the `userFollowers` subcollection, and therefore cannot execute the above batched write.